# Should I transfer a growing potted blueberry bush to a bigger pot, or into the ground?

Tags: containers, shrubs, transplanting, blueberries

I have a blueberry bush in a smallish pot.  It was given to us a couple of summers ago, and we put it in the only available pot we had at the time.

This year, we've had a pretty good yield from it, considering its size.  The fact that we now have a one-year-old daughter who loves blueberries means that we're thinking about putting the blueberry bush either in a larger pot, or planting it out in the border between a small apple tree and a small cherry tree.

So my question is - should we transfer it to a large pot, or put it in the soil?  It's a clay soil, if that helps.  If so, when is the best time to do it?

I'm in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether its clay or not isn't an issue - the issue is they like acidic soil conditions, not alkaline. If your garden grows Pieris, Rhododendron, Camellia or blue hydrangeas well, then you can bet its on the acidic side, so plant the blueberry out in autumn. Dig over the area first and incorporate some good garden compost, or soil conditioning compost from the garden centre prior to planting. If your soil is alkaline, probably best to buy a larger pot and use ericaceous compost.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo, some great info.  The chap next door is a keen gardener, I'll ask him about the soil type.  He doesn't do much by way of fruit plants, so he didn't know blueberries.  Thanks again.